# What Is Projection On Subspace $U$ In Parallel To Subspace $V?$

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

When I am given that a transformation $T$ is a projection on $U$ in parallel to $V$, the projection "sits" in $V?$

Comment: Can you clarify what $A$ and $B$ in the question title are? You don't mention them in the body of your question.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Edited

Comment: One way to explain the transformation is as follows: for any $u \in U$ and $v \in V$, we have $T(u + v) = u$

Comment: “Parallel to $V$” generally means that $V=\ker T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this means is that $T$ is a linear operator on a vector space $W$, which is the direct sum of $U$ and $V$. That is, for every vector $w \in W$, there is a unique $u \in U$ and $v \in V$ such that $w = u + v$. Further, it means that $T(w) = u$. Since $$T(w) - w = u - (u + v) = -v$$
the line through $w$ and $T(w)$ is always parallel to $V$.

Also $T(w) = 0 \iff w = 0 + v = v \in V$, so as amd said, $V = \ker T$. And $U = \operatorname{im} T$.