# Determine the projector $P$ along subspace $W$ onto subspace $U$?

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

Suppose that $\{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n; b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_r\}$ is a basis for vector space $V\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, where $n+r=m$. There is no inner product defined in $V$.

Let $U=\text{span}(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n), W=\text{span}(b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_r)$, thus $V=U\oplus W$.

How to determine the projection $P$ along $W$ onto $U$?

I stuck halfway below:

Let $A_{m\times n}=(a_1, a_2,\cdots, a_n), B_{m\times r}=(b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_r)$.
Since $\text{range}(P)=U$, I can assume that $P=AX$ for some $X_{n\times m}$. As $X$ has degree of freedom $nm$, I need $nm$ equations to determine $X$.

On the other hand, the complement of $P$ is $I-P$, which is a projector along $U$ onto $W$, this implies that $(I-P)=BY$ for some $Y_{r\times m}$. To determine $Y$, I need $rm$ equations.

So it seems that I have a choice here: determine $X$ or $Y$. Suppose $n<r$, then I choose to determine $X$:

$P^2=P\implies AXAX=AX\implies XA=I_n$. This gives $n^2$ equations. I still need $rn$ equations for determine $X$, those should come from the condition that $\text{range}(I-P)=W$, but I don't how to proceed from here.

Comment: Hints: What are the values of $P(a_i)$ and $P(b_j)$? Those values completely determine $P$, but if you must continue, knowing the images of the basis vectors, what does the matrix of $P$ relative to this basis look like?

Comment: Aha, yes, $P(a_i)=a_i, P(b_j)=0$ gives $mm$ equations which in turn completely determines $P$. For the second part of your hints, did you mean that $P(a_i)=a_i, P(b_j)=0$ indicates that the eigenvalues of $P$ are 1s (and 0s)?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Now I am puzzled from another point of view: suppose that $P$ can be obtained from $P=AX_{n\times m}$. There are $nm$ unknowns in $X$. Using $P(a_i)=AXa_i=a_i, i=1,2,\cdots,n$, there are exactly $nm$ constrains, which implies that using $P(a_i)=a_i$ alone is sufficient to determine $X$ thus $P$. But this should not be true. What's wrong in the reasoning?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2827354